# XMLHttpRequest() send NS_ERROR_FAILURE for localhost with absolute OR relative path

Tags: javascript, ajax, localhost

I get the following error in Firefox 31 ESR:

> Error: NS_ERROR_FAILURE:
>
> Source file:
>
> http://localhost/Example/scripts/index.js Line: 18

Here is the same thing from Internet Explorer 11:

> SCRIPT5022: InvalidStateError

Here is my script that does the call *to* the AJAX function:

```
ajax('post','standard/','part='+p+'&price='+q,'sequel_sub_object_key');
```

Here is my AJAX function:

```
function ajax(method,url,param_id_container_pos,id_container,id_focus,sequel)
{
 var methods = Array('get','head','post');

 if (window.XMLHttpRequest && in_array(method,methods))
 {
  xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open(method,url,true);//Error triggers here for localhost.

  if (method=='post')
  {
   xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
   xhr.send(param_id_container_pos);
  }

  xhr.send(null);

  xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
  {console.log('xhr.readyState = '+xhr.readyState);
   if (xhr.readyState=='4')
   {
    alert('xhr.responseText = '+xhr.responseText);
   }
  }
 }
```

Apparently Firefox and IE *very vaguely* think I'm doing cross site scripting ... on *localhost*?

For the URL I've tried passing absolute and relative paths:

1. `document.getElementsByTagName('base')[0].href+'standard/'`
2. `window.location.href`
3. `'standard'`

I've looked up a couple dozen pages most of which are here on Stack and the questions are all off.

1. I have zero intention of cross-site scripting.
2. I'm *not* changing the `method`.
3. I'm not using a different protocol (all HTTP, not HTTPS).
4. I'm not using *any* subdomains.
5. I *never* rely on or weaken my code with frameworks.
6. I do *not* care if the URL *must* be absolute or relative, I *just* need it to work.
7. This is for an intranet website.
8. The server and client are *both* the same computer.
9. The originating URL is formatted as: `http://localhost/Client/standard/?http-query`
10. The target URL is `http://localhost/Client/standard/`.
11. The Apache Access log shows that the request goes through and returns HTTP 200.
12. An `alert()` immediately after `open`
13. None of the states for `onreadystatechange` are logged in the console.
14. Not all parameters *need* to be set when calling the `ajax` function.

What am I missing?

Comment: readyState is a number, not a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `send()` twice for the same XHR object, that's probably where the error comes from, as that would trigger an `InvalidStateError` as the object is not open anymore, it's already sending.

```
function ajax(method, url, param_id_container_pos, id_container, id_focus, sequel) {
    ....

        if (method == 'post') {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
            xhr.send(param_id_container_pos); // you're sending here
        }

        xhr.send(null); // and then again here, which triggers an error

        ..........
```

Also, you should generally url encode the data you're sending

```
var data = 'part=' + encodeURIComponent(p) +'&price=' + encodeURIComponent(q);
ajax('post', 'standard/', data, 'sequel_sub_object_key');
```

All together

```
var data = 'part=' + encodeURIComponent(p) +'&price=' + encodeURIComponent(q);

ajax('post', 'standard/', data, 'sequel_sub_object_key');

function ajax(method, url, param_id_container_pos, id_container, id_focus, sequel) {
    var methods = ['get', 'head', 'post'];

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest && methods.indexOf(method) != -1) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhr.open(method, url, true);

        if (method == 'post') {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
            xhr.send(param_id_container_pos);
        } else {
            xhr.send(null);
        }

        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                alert('xhr.responseText = ' + xhr.responseText);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Need a few minutes to make sure it's not a post error.

Comment: Yeah, missed that. I just moved it in to it's own condition for GET requests. I get the other advice and yeah on my older/mature system it's all encoded correctly. Thanks!